# The use of intimate relationship as a mashal for g-dliness in chasidus and kabala

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sexuality, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, allegory-mashal

I in a shiur a story was told that it was asked:

Why the relations between a man and woman are used as the mashal (since for chastity it is preferred not to use it, if you have the option).
And it was answered: that there is no other mashal that can be used (that is similar/good enough)

Is there a source for this?

Comment: "since for chastity it is preferred not to use it, if you have the option" What?

Comment: Could add some reference to Hassidut or Kabbalah for such a metaphor?

Comment: Araowsal (isarusa) from above araowsal from below, hamshocho from above hamshocho from bellow, male water female waters... maybe later I will add sources

Comment: Regarding the first comment, the way I see it is that the Torah avoids to discuss details of the sexual act when possible for tznius purposes

Comment: Is English your first language? If Hebrew works better, you can comment in Hebrew; many (most?) users have some degree of familiarity with Hebrew. You can also use [online translators](https://translate.google.com/)

Comment: The Baal Shem Tov is the source.

Comment: @Yishai where? please

Comment: Wouldn't the source be Shir HaShirim?

Comment: @hazoriz, http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1991820/jewish/The-Taboo-of-Studying-Kabbalah.htm paragraph starting "First of all, when discussing the mystical dynamics of creation ..."

Comment: @Yishai this answer I will expect, but will be better to have the source for the story , now that I have the names I will try to look myself

Comment: @user6591 Yes, the allegory starts with Shlomo HaMelech in Shir HaShirim. There are earlier references via tzerufim, like for example, the letters of miluy of the name שדי which pertain to the union of husband & wife. But this is not as explicit as Shir HaShirim. I do not understand what the OP is asking here. This question needs to be revised & clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Very good question.
I think that you can find this mashal in almost all prophets (to read haftarot will give a good sample) and in Shir Hashirim 
See Mishna Yadaym 3, 5:

> אָמַר רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא, חַס וְשָׁלוֹם, לֹא נֶחֱלַק אָדָם מִיִּשְׂרָאֵל עַל שִׁיר הַשִּׁירִים שֶׁלֹּא תְטַמֵּא אֶת הַיָּדַיִם, שֶׁאֵין כָּל הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ כְדַאי כַּיּוֹם שֶׁנִּתַּן בּוֹ שִׁיר הַשִּׁירִים לְיִשְׂרָאֵל, שֶׁכָּל הַכְּתוּבִים קֹדֶשׁ, וְשִׁיר הַשִּׁירִים קֹדֶשׁ קָדָשִׁים.  ‏

Brachot 57b:

> If one sees the Songs of Songs in a dream, he may hope for piety;

In several passages in Navi you can see more, even incestual relations. Instead, in Kabbala, there are some very explicit expression (See Atkinu Seudata of leil Shabbat.)

BTW, may be that the great interest and curiosity of people toward relationship is not rational. The relationship between Adam and Chava is called **"to know"**. Basically the **main basic seeking of human being** is to know and male-female relationship are a kind of Mashal. The Chachamim-Neviim make it back the search of truth.

I know that this answer is not accurate enough. I need to give citations of Neviim, Zohar and R. Ch. Vital. (don't forget that at time of Tanayim and amorayim, Aramean was known as English today)

But an important point is that some things do not be said when a large people is present. (See the end of Masechet Megila) and it is prohibited to make songs from verse of Shir Hashirim (Gemara Sanhedrin 101a*). (*infinite game of mirrors* between mashal and nimshal)

---

- תנו רבנן הקורא פסוק של שיר השירים ועושה אותו כמין זמר והקורא פסוק בבית משתאות בלא זמנו מביא רעה לעולם מפני שהתורה חוגרת שק ועומדת לפני הקב''ה ואומרת לפניו רבונו של עולם עשאוני בניך ככנור שמנגנין בו לצים

Comment: +1 thank you but it is not what I am looking for

Comment: @hazoriz Can you explain more if I do not understand you correctly, I'll try to understand again,

Comment: One should really be a mekubal before discussing kabbalic concepts. Most words in kabala are meaningless to others.

Comment: @kouty "it is prohibited to make songs from verse of Shir Hashirim" Source?

Comment: @SAH fixed, gemara in Sanhedrin, it is not exactly an isur תנו רבנן הקורא פסוק של שיר השירים ועושה אותו כמין זמר והקורא פסוק בבית משתאות בלא זמנו מביא רעה לעולם מפני שהתורה חוגרת שק ועומדת לפני הקב''ה ואומרת לפניו רבונו של עולם עשאוני בניך ככנור שמנגנין בו לצים

Comment: @kouty Thanks. It would seem, though, that the same "prohibition" applies to all pesukim...?

Comment: @SAH maybe.....

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you would say it is the other way round, the most intense form of intimacy we can experience is a mashal for an intensity of intimacy not able to be experienced in this world.

See Rav Gifter's introduction to Artscroll Shir Hashirim.